# collectionView picking up the wrong data

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionViewCell subclass that has two buttons "add to cart" and "Remove". I have already programmed for showing remove on that cell which is already added to the cart, but the collectionView is only changing the title of the last product added. I think there is some issue with reusing the cell.

Here is my cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
- (ShoppingCellCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ShoppingCellCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ShoppingViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     NSString *imgURLSTR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",IMAGE_BASEURL,[[[data valueForKey:@"products"] valueForKey:@"imagepath"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    imgURLSTR = [imgURLSTR stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"/"];
    [cell.itemImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURLSTR] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"telebuy_logo.png"]];

    [cell.itemTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[data valueForKey:@"products"] valueForKey:@"desc"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [cell.rateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INR %@",[[[data valueForKey:@"products"] valueForKey:@"salevalue"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    [cell.featureButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(featuresBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.featureButtonOutlet setTag:indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary*dict = [[data valueForKey:@"products"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    NSString* singleProductFromAllProducts = [dict valueForKey:@"id"];

    for (int i = 0 ; i<dataC.count; i++) {

        if ([singleProductFromAllProducts isEqualToString:[[dataC objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"prodid"]]) {

            NSLog(@"Item is %@",[[dataC objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"prodid"]);
            NSLog(@"%@",singleProductFromAllProducts);

            [cell.addToCartButtonOutlet setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cell.addToCartButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        }
        else
        {
            [cell.addToCartButtonOutlet setTitle:@"Add To Cart" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cell.addToCartButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }
    [cell.addToCartButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(addToCartBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.addToCartButtonOutlet setTag:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

where addToCartButtonOutlet is the button outlet, dataC is an array of products which are added to the cart, and "singleProductFromAllProducts" is the product at indexPath. I am comparing each product to the dataC's product if the product is available in dataC, then changing the button outlet to remove, but it is only showing remove only on one product.

here is my custom class of UICollectionViewCell

```
#import "ShoppingCellCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ShoppingViewController.h"

@implementation ShoppingCellCollectionViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    _itemImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    _itemImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;


    [_addToCartButtonOutlet setBackgroundColor:[APPDELEGATE colorFromHexString:@"#035098"]];
    [_addToCartButtonOutlet setBackgroundColor:[APPDELEGATE colorFromHexString:@"#ee1c25"]];
}
```

Need help.

Comment: You really haven't noticed your formatting is totally off?